# Excel spreadsheet scrolls right uncontrollably

Tags: excel

Did an office works update....now excel spreadsheet with data opens but as soon as i touch to input info it  runs away and scrolls to the right endlessly. Unable to input new data.
Shows "normal view" at bottom

Comment: What if you use Word, does anything funky happen there? Second - when you open the workbook, it sits there like normal.  When you go to click a cell, it starts scrolling? Or when you touch a key, it starts scrolling?  Try and pinpoint exactly what you're doing that causes it to move, and add that to your OP.

Comment: Word is normal.  When opening workbook it sits there like normal. When i click on a cell it sets off the scrolling.  Does this with all spreadsheets saved

Comment: And, just to make sure, you're positive it's not a hardware issue? Hm, is there any way to open the old Office Works on your computer?  When it's scrolling, press `ESC`, what happens?  What if you hold down LEFT?

Comment: cannot open old office….when scrolling ESC doesn't  help.  Pressing  mouse stops scrolling but upon releasing scrolling continues.  Tried removing all bluetooth devices (keyboard and mouse) but same scrolling problem

Answer (score 16):

Better late than never. This same issue happened to me today. After viewing sites around the net with "suggestions" like reinstalling windows or debugging in safe mode...I figured out the solution.

Detach and reattach your wireless mouse dongle and replace the batteries in your mouse.

For some reason, in this particular setup, when the wireless mouse is close to dying, you get an uncontrollable scrolling in Excel. Replacing the battery alone does not seem to fix it, nor does rebooting/etc. Only once you've replace the battery and reinserted the dongle will the uncontrollable scrolling resolve.

This issue is rare enough that it's incredibly difficult to find an answer online. Hope this helps any future uncontrollable scroller!

Comment: This fixed the problem for me too. I can't remember the last time I replaced the mouse battery, so it's been a long time. I didn't need to restart the computer or anything. Such a bizarre symptom for a dying mouse battery, though.

Comment: Thanks! I only needed to unplug and plug the dongle back in! (Battery has been replaced recently - for a regular flat battery issue)

Comment: Actually, Adobe products (Indesign, Illustrator & Photoshop) have the same symptoms in this situation --- that's the problem I've been trying to solve all afternoon!! The only advice you find online is re-installing all Creative Cloud apps but that does nothing; it's the restart afterwards that works. And similar to Word, Acrobat Pro, does not have the sideways sickness...  I did indeed swap batteries last week, now first time using Adobe Creative Cloud apps.

Comment: This annoying issue has happened to me today. Tried options, such as turning off/on the scroll lock and rebooted the laptop. They did not help. But finally detached and reattached the wireless dongle and the scrolling stopped.